# can we specify color of points in bokeh using some column of the dataframe as in ggplot?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, python-ggplot

In ggplot we can do `ggplot(data,aes(x='col1',y='col2',color='col3'))`
this will give points color based on the values of **col3** even if the values in **col3** aren't explicit color names **(like red,green,etc)**
How can we do something like this with bokeh

Answer (score 1):

[Bokeh palettes](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html) store colors in lists. The `plot` function needs a explicit value. 
For example -

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Greys
p=figure()
color=Greys[3][1] #See the pyramid in the above mentioned link
p.line([1,2,3],[2,3,2],color=color)
show(p)
```